# Printing issue using java's printf method

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print a percentage sign using printf.
When I use the following:

```
System.out.printf("%-3d%%\n",10);
System.out.printf("%-3d%%\n",100);
System.out.printf("%-3d%%\n",0);
```

I end up with:

```
10 %  
100%
0  %
```

How can I achieve the following

```
10%   - 1 space after % sign
100%  - no space 
0%    - 2 spaces after % sign
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s\n",10 + "%");
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s\n",100+ "%");
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s\n",0+ "%");
```

this can be verified with

```
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s|\n",10 + "%");
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s|\n",100 + "%");
    System.out.printf("%-4.4s|\n",0+ "%");
```

which produces

```
10% |
100%|
0%  |
```

Answer (score 1):

try with DecimalFormat..

```
    DecimalFormat df=new  DecimalFormat("###'%'");
    System.out.printf("%s\n",df.format(10));
    System.out.printf("%s\n",df.format(1));
    System.out.printf("%s\n",df.format(100));
```